# Real Analysis: Given $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, which set is open, which is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

a. $A_1 = \{x: \sin(1/x) =0\}$

Clearly $\sin(1/x) = 0$ for $x = \frac{1}{n\pi}$, what can we say about this set?

b. $A_2 = \{x: x\sin(1/x)= 0 \}$

Again $\sin(1/x) = 0$ for $x = \frac{1}{n\pi}$, is there any difference between this set and $A_1$?

c. $A_3 = \{x: \sin(1/x) > 0 \}$

$\sin(\frac{1}{x}) > 0$ if $\frac{1}{x} > \sin^{-1} (0) $, so $x > 0$ is an open set. Am I correct?

Comment: For $A_1$: To be open, every point in the set must be an interior point; does $A_1$ have any interior points? To be closed, a set must contain all its limit points; 0 is a limit point of $A_1$, but is 0 an element of $A_1$?

Comment: $A_2=A_1\cup \{0\}$. For c: $\sin(1/x)>0\Leftrightarrow x\in \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z} (2\pi n,\, \pi + 2pi n)$

Comment: For case 2 - xsin(1/x) is continuous at 0, so you can include 0 as one of the points of A2. Your reasoning is incorrect in case 3 - sin(1/x) oscillates between -1 and 1 as x gets close to zero, you can cook up a similar sequence as in case A1, where sin(1/x) > 0 between elements of the sequence (hint).

Answer (score 1):

The maps $f(x) =\sin(1/x)$ and $g(x)= x\sin(1/x)$ are continuous. Note that: $$A_1 = f^{-1}(\{0\}), \quad A_2 = g^{-1}(\{0\}), \quad A_3 = f^{-1}(\left[0,+\infty\right[).$$We have that $\{0\}$ is closed and $\left[0,+\infty\right[$ is open, so...